# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client when use respone.json()

Tags: javascript, json, express

I want to create an API for get data. But, the function res.json() found the problem according to the message below

```
web_1         | Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
web_1         |     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:533:11)
web_1         |     at ServerResponse.header (/mbs_welfare/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
web_1         |     at ServerResponse.send (/mbs_welfare/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
web_1         |     at /mbs_welfare/server.js:45:9
web_1         |     at Layer.handle_error (/mbs_welfare/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
web_1         |     at trim_prefix (/mbs_welfare/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
web_1         |     at /mbs_welfare/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
web_1         |     at Function.process_params (/mbs_welfare/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
web_1         |     at next (/mbs_welfare/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
web_1         |     at Layer.handle_error (/mbs_welfare/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)
```

l

```
router.get('/profile/user/me', async (req, res, next) => {
    let user = req.session.user;
    if(user) {
        try {
            let me = user.adminID
            let info = await knex('admin_accounts').where('adminID', me)
            res.json(info)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../public/personal_information.html'));
    }else{
         res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

Comment: You can't do both `res.json` and `res.sendFile`. Is a request on the path `profile/user/me` supposed to get a response that is an HTML document or a JSON document? It can't be both.

Comment: Do you still need help with your question or did my answer solve it? Please let me know so I could help you out. Thanks.

Comment: @JakubASuplicki Your answer made me understand the problem. In this case, I created another app.get() route. Thank you.

Comment: @Merphy, perfect. That is good to hear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appears because `res` is called more than once in your code, that is:

`res.json(info)` - here and then

`res.sendFile` - here as well, for example

You need to make sure `res` is called only once at a time.

In other words, only one `response` is allowed per `request`.

Hope it helps.